# Program crashes when given a big number

Tags: c, crash, bigdata, dynamic-memory-allocation, mergesort

I'm trying to make a `merge sort algorithm` in C. The problem is that it does not work for a big number of elements. If the array has 100000 elements it's OK but if it has 1e6 or 1e7 then it crashes. I thought that you cannot give such a big number of elements for an array but after I have read that this is not true, you should be able to give 1e7 elements. After that I thought that maybe `int` range is to small but that's not the case, `int` goes to 1e9. I don't really know what's the problem and why it doesn't work, so please help. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n;
void merge(int *, int, int);
void mergeSort(int *, int, int);
void bubbleSort(int *, int);

int main() {
//    scanf("%d",&n);
    n = 10000000;
    int *a = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if (a == NULL) {
        printf("Nu s-a putut aloca memorie.");
        exit(0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = rand() % 50;

    mergeSort(a, 0, n - 1);
    //bubbleSort(a, n - 1);

//  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
//      printf("%d ", a[i]);
//  }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}

void merge(int *a, int start, int sfarsit) {
    int mij = (start + sfarsit) / 2;
    int i = start;
    int j = mij + 1;
    int k = start;
    int aux[10000000];

    while (i <= mij && j <= sfarsit) {
        if (a[i] < a[j])
            aux[k++] = a[i++];
        else
            aux[k++] = a[j++];
    }
    while (i <= mij)
        aux[k++] = a[i++];
    while (j <= sfarsit)
        aux[k++] = a[j++];
    for (int i = start; i <= sfarsit; i++)
        a[i] = aux[i];
}

void mergeSort(int *a, int start, int sfarsit) {
    if (start >= sfarsit)
        return ;

    int mij = (start + sfarsit) / 2;

    mergeSort(a, start, mij);
    mergeSort(a, mij + 1, sfarsit);
    merge(a, start, sfarsit);
}
```

Comment: Did you actually use `int aux[10000000];` with the smaller (successful) numbers of elements? 40 Mb is rather large for a stack variable.

Comment: `aux` is too small? You will need to malloc `aux` too.

Comment: @MihalacheRares: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
int aux[10000000];
```

is problem. That will be to much for the stack to handle. Change to this:

```
int *aux = malloc(sizeof(*aux) * 10000000);
```

Of course, you need to use `free(aux)` in the end of the function `merge` and also check if the allocation was successful.

Also, you should of course allocate in relation to `sfarsit` but judging from your other code, it does not seem like I need to tell you that.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has this problem: the definition `int aux[10000000];` in the `merge` function defines a temporary array with automatic storage (aka *on the stack*) which is:

- very large, potentially too large for your system, causing a **stack overflow**.
- not necessary large enough if the array to be sorted is larger than 10 million elements.

You should allocate this temporary array, either locally in `merge` or in a wrapper function that would call `mergesort` with an extra argument.

It is also unnecessary and quite error prone to make `n` a global variable.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int mergeSort(int *a, int length);
void bubbleSort(int *, int);

int main() {
    int n;
    int *a;

    n = 10000000;
    //scanf("%d", &n);
    if ((a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * n)) == NULL) {
        printf("Nu s-a putut aloca memorie.");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = rand() % 50;

    mergeSort(a, n);
    //bubbleSort(a, n);

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] < a[i - 1]) {
            printf("mergeSort failed\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}

void merge(int *a, int start, int mij, int sfarsit, int *aux) {
    int i = start;
    int j = mij + 1;
    int k = start;

    while (i <= mij && j <= sfarsit) {
        if (a[i] <= a[j])
            aux[k++] = a[i++];
        else
            aux[k++] = a[j++];
    }
    while (i <= mij)
        aux[k++] = a[i++];

    while (j <= sfarsit)
        aux[k++] = a[j++];

    for (i = start; i <= sfarsit; i++)
        a[i] = aux[i];
}

void mergeSortAux(int *a, int start, int sfarsit, int *aux) {
    if (start >= sfarsit)
        return;

    int mij = (start + sfarsit) / 2;

    mergeSortAux(a, start, mij, aux);
    mergeSortAux(a, mij + 1, sfarsit, aux);
    merge(a, start, mij, sfarsit, aux);
}

int mergeSort(int *a, int length) {
    if (length > 1) {
        int *aux = malloc(sizeof(*aux) * length);
        if (aux == NULL)
            return -1;
        mergeSortAux(a, 0, length - 1, aux);
        free(aux);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you can improve this code:

- using `size_t` instead of `int` for the array sizes and index variables
- using the convention `start` included and `stop` excluded, which avoids the `+1`/`-1` adjustments.
- by not copying the remaining values from the right slice as they are already in place in the original array.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int mergeSort(int *a, size_t length);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    size_t n = 10000000;
    int *a;
    int res = 0;

    if (argc > 1) {
        n = strtoll(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    }
    if ((a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * n)) == NULL) {
        printf("Nu s-a putut aloca memorie.");
        return 1;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % 50;
    }
    if (mergeSort(a, n)) {
        printf("mergeSort failed: allocation error\n");
        res = 1;
    } else {
        for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (a[i] < a[i - 1]) {
                printf("mergeSort failed: out of order\n");
                res = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    free(a);
    return res;
}

void merge(int *a, size_t start, size_t mid, size_t stop, int *aux) {
    size_t i = start;
    size_t j = mid;
    size_t k = start;

    while (i < mid && j < stop) {
        if (a[i] <= a[j])
            aux[k++] = a[i++];
        else
            aux[k++] = a[j++];
    }
    while (i < mid)
        aux[k++] = a[i++];

    for (i = start; i < k; i++)
        a[i] = aux[i];
}

void mergeSortAux(int *a, size_t start, size_t stop, int *aux) {
    if (stop - start >= 2) {
        size_t mid = start + (stop - start) / 2;

        mergeSortAux(a, start, mid, aux);
        mergeSortAux(a, mid, stop, aux);
        merge(a, start, mid, stop, aux);
    }
}

int mergeSort(int *a, size_t length) {
    if (length > 1) {
        int *aux = malloc(sizeof(*aux) * length);
        if (aux == NULL)
            return -1;
        mergeSortAux(a, 0, length, aux);
        free(aux);
    }
    return 0;
}
```